# Remove dollar sign if it is first character of pasted command

Tags: command-line, terminator

When giving examples of shell commands people will often prefix each line with the `$` to illustrate it should be ran in terminal. Most recently I encountered it on [this Github page](https://github.com/neutronth/speedtest-lite).

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl netcat-openbsd bc pv
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neutronth/speedtest-lite/master/speedtest-lite
```

When these lines are triple clicked the dollar sign (being part of that line) is of course part of the selection. Is there a way to set my terminal (I'm using Terminator) so that if `$` is the first character of a command, to ignore it?

Comment: Just realized I could make an alias to accomplish this task. However I'd like to know if there is a more "official" way besides what I'd consider to be a workaround

Comment: You can press `^X^E` to open your commandline in your default text editor (set with the `EDITOR` envirionment variable).  You can then edit to taste before executing.  For example, in `vim`, paste the text, and you can use `:s/^$//` to remove dollarsign prefixes from every line.

Comment: I think people should just not copy paste commands, personally... It's always safer to toe them out manually, it helps you think about what you're doing and what might happen because of it

Comment: there is no "official" way, but you can always do  `alias "$"=""` in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set out to answer this question, and it turned out to be a little more involved then I thought. With a little bash magic:

```
    cat file | while read x; do OUTPUT=$(echo $x | sed 's/^.//'); eval $OUTPUT; done
```

What this does is prints file to standard output, reads each line, removes the first character, and stores the result in $OUTPUT, then runs the line in $OUTPUT as a command with eval. Be careful when using eval, this script will run an entire file as commands.